# How to handle "Close" button of APN popup?

Tags: iphone

I need to call a webservice when user clicks on "close" or "view" button of APN popup.
when user clicks "view" button, control goes to program through didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and didReceiveRemoteNotification methods and i can call webservice from there. but when user clicks "close" button, nothing happens.So, where should I write code for webservice on click of "close" button?

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Close button is only to discard/cancel the notification which is handled by the OS.

Comment: So, is there any way that my app come to know programatically that APN is received. considering user taps "close" button?

Comment: On server side u need set the payload u need to show. Like u can show the badges which will notify user that there is an update for that application.                                                          More Detail: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: adding payload will just add message on popup for user.I need my app come to know that popup has arrived.(if view btn is tapped its possible but not in case of close btn. plz help)

Comment: There is no way to do that, since the push notification is handled by the OS not your app.